# RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (2, 1, 15), got [2, 16, 15]

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm trying to apply a Seq2Seq architecture to time series data, and I am getting this error:

> RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (2, 1, 15), got [2, 16, 15]

I can tell that the error has something to do with the LSTM in my decoder, but I am unable to resolve this.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Here are the encoder and decoder classes:

```python
class Encoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.hid_dim = hid_dim
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(input_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout=dropout, batch_first=True)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        outputs, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(x)
        return hidden, cell

class Decoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, output_dim, input_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.output_dim = output_dim
        self.hid_dim = hid_dim
        self.n_layers = n_layers
        self.rnn = nn.LSTM(output_dim, hid_dim, n_layers, dropout=dropout, batch_first=True)
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(hid_dim, output_dim)
        
    def forward(self, input, hidden, cell):
        input = input.unsqueeze(0).view(1, -1, 3)
        output, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(input, (hidden, cell))
        prediction = self.fc_out(output.squeeze(0))
        return prediction, hidden, cell
```

and here is my seq2seq class as well:

```python
class Seq2Seq(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, encoder, decoder, device):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.encoder = encoder
        self.decoder = decoder
        self.device = device
    
    def forward(self, X, y, teacher_forcing_ratio = 0.5):
        batch_size = y.shape[1]
        y_len = y.shape[0]
        y_size = self.decoder.output_dim
        
        outputs = torch.zeros(y_len, batch_size, y_size).to(self.device)
        hidden, cell = self.encoder(X)
        input = y[0, :]
        
        for t in range(1, y_len):
            output, hidden, cell = self.decoder(input, hidden, cell)
            outputs[t] = output
            teacher_force = random.random() < teacher_forcing_ratio
            input = y[t] if teacher_force else output
        return outputs
```

Full traceback:

```python
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/jv/4n9t0z4x1hq19bqjlw2x7f840000gn/T/ipykernel_75254/278735545.py in <module>
      9     start_time = time.time()
     10 
---> 11     train_loss = train(model, train_dataloader, optimizer, criterion, CLIP)
     12     valid_loss = evaluate(model, valid_dataloader, criterion)
     13 

/var/folders/jv/4n9t0z4x1hq19bqjlw2x7f840000gn/T/ipykernel_75254/2834982788.py in train(model, iterator, optimizer, criterion, clip)
     12         optimizer.zero_grad()
     13 
---> 14         output = model(X, y)
     15         output_dim = output.shape[-1]
     16 

~/anaconda3/envs/neural_ode/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/var/folders/jv/4n9t0z4x1hq19bqjlw2x7f840000gn/T/ipykernel_75254/1027058398.py in forward(self, X, y, teacher_forcing_ratio)
     17 
     18         for t in range(1, y_len):
---> 19             output, hidden, cell = self.decoder(input, hidden, cell)
     20             outputs[t] = output
     21             teacher_force = random.random() < teacher_forcing_ratio

~/anaconda3/envs/neural_ode/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

/var/folders/jv/4n9t0z4x1hq19bqjlw2x7f840000gn/T/ipykernel_75254/3738750061.py in forward(self, input, hidden, cell)
     24         input = input.unsqueeze(0).view(1, -1, 3)
     25         print(input.shape)
---> 26         output, (hidden, cell) = self.rnn(input, (hidden, cell))
     27         prediction = self.fc_out(output.squeeze(0))
     28         return prediction, hidden, cell

~/anaconda3/envs/neural_ode/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, **kwargs)
   1100         if not (self._backward_hooks or self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or _global_backward_hooks
   1101                 or _global_forward_hooks or _global_forward_pre_hooks):
-> 1102             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
   1103         # Do not call functions when jit is used
   1104         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks = [], []

~/anaconda3/envs/neural_ode/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in forward(self, input, hx)
    687             hx = self.permute_hidden(hx, sorted_indices)
    688 
--> 689         self.check_forward_args(input, hx, batch_sizes)
    690         if batch_sizes is None:
    691             result = _VF.lstm(input, hx, self._flat_weights, self.bias, self.num_layers,

~/anaconda3/envs/neural_ode/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in check_forward_args(self, input, hidden, batch_sizes)
    631                            ):
    632         self.check_input(input, batch_sizes)
--> 633         self.check_hidden_size(hidden[0], self.get_expected_hidden_size(input, batch_sizes),
    634                                'Expected hidden[0] size {}, got {}')
    635         self.check_hidden_size(hidden[1], self.get_expected_cell_size(input, batch_sizes),

~/anaconda3/envs/neural_ode/lib/python3.9/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/rnn.py in check_hidden_size(self, hx, expected_hidden_size, msg)
    224                           msg: str = 'Expected hidden size {}, got {}') -> None:
    225         if hx.size() != expected_hidden_size:
--> 226             raise RuntimeError(msg.format(expected_hidden_size, list(hx.size())))
    227 
    228     def check_forward_args(self, input: Tensor, hidden: Tensor, batch_sizes: Optional[Tensor]):

RuntimeError: Expected hidden[0] size (2, 1, 15), got [2, 16, 15]
```

Comment: Please provide a full traceback for the error and indicate what line in your provided code the error relates to specifically.

Comment: why do you hard code the batch size as 3 in your `forward` pass?

Comment: @Grismar I've added the traceback. The error seems to occur on line 19 of the Seq2Seq class, when the decoder is called.

Comment: @Shai just updated my code. I get the same error even after setting batch_size to y.shape[1]

Comment: @ashcher51 if you are running with `batch_first=True`, shouldn't;t `batch_size=y.shape[0]`?

Comment: That's a lot clearer - it's definitely clear where the error occurs, and more or less why. However without access to code that actually causes this error (and runs), it's hard to say what's wrong exactly. I don't have enough experience with these libraries to say, someone who does might, but I'd recommend trying to come up with a minimal example that still has the issue (even if it does nothing useful), so that people can look at the problem more closely - but also for yourself to try and analyse the problem and come up with a solution (that hopefully translates to the real problem)